# Using XSLT to output an empty HTML textarea element

Tags: .net, html, xslt, textarea

When attempting to output an empty textarea element, the .NET XSLT processor collapses the element to its short form. Instead of this:

```
<textarea id="blah" name="blah"></textarea>
```

I get this:

```
<textarea id="blah" name="blah"/>
```

Which causes many web browsers (including IE and Firefox) to render the rest of the page as if it were the *contents* of the textarea. **This sucks.**

I can force the XSLT processor to output both the opening and closing textarea tags if I place something in between like a non-breaking space. But that means I have to do more parsing and validation on the client side to tell when the textarea is "truly" empty. I also have to use JavaScript to remove the extra space so that users don't begin their comments with a blank space.

Does anyone know of a way to force the XSLT processor to render both the opening and closing tags *without* having to insert dummy content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find your answer via a similar question right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336670/explicit-script-end-tag-always-converted-to-self-closing) on Stackoverflow.com :-)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.outputmethod.aspx) is further explanation from MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

I you have to use dummy content, this was the xsl:template I used, having just the Line Feed character inside the textarea.

```
<!-- This prevents empty textarea elements being rendered as singletons in the XHTML output by adding a newline character -->
<xsl:template name="xhtml-textarea-contents">
    <!-- what should be contained in the textarea -->
    <xsl:param name="contents" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$contents = ''"><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="$contents" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris Ballance had an answer that worked for me. But it's worth noting that I had been using an overload of XslCompiledTransform that output to a stream, like so:

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
...
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
transform.Transform(reader, args, stream);
```

In order to pass the correct settings along, I had to use the overload that accepted an XmlWriter instead.

```
// using XmlWriter so I can pass the output settings along.
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, transform.OutputSettings);
transform.Transform(reader, args, writer);
```

Microsoft's using a really odd design pattern there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating an xml or html, you can write a newline inside the textarea and then remove it with jquery.

This is an example with jQuery:

```
<textarea>&#160;<textarea>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').each(
      function(index){$(this).text('');}
     );
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this issue outside of .net, which is reproducible [for me] in both `<xsl:output method="xml">` and `<xsl:output method="xhtml">` (I'm making an assumption that `method="html"` is inapplicable to our scenario where output has to be well-formed xml)

To avoid the textarea tag from collapsing we have to insert some content into it, but we also have to avoid tampering with *actual* content. The following:

```
<xsl:if test="not(normalize-space())"><xsl:comment></xsl:comment></xsl:if>
```

produces correct results (i.e. prevents empty `textarea` from self-closing and does not introduce artificial content). I believe this behaviour is mentioned in spec under [node construction from post-schema-validation infoset](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-xpath-datamodel-30-20131022/#const-psvi-element), where empty comments' string values would become zero length strings; however the document's phrasing is waaay too w3-ey for light afternoon reading.

Pushing it a bit further (*so if it doesn't tamper with content, do we really need `xsl:if`?*), this is the final template that prevents certain tags from collapsing (I aspire to follow the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) pattern):

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="textarea">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <xsl:comment></xsl:comment>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

NB: browsers' behaviour would suggest this transformation should be applied to some other elements as well, like paragraphs. Having a self-closing `<p/>`, however, is not as destructive as having a self-closing `<textarea/>`!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and just realized that if you set the ConformanceLevel of the XmlWriterSettings to Fragment, it eliminates some of the XslCompiledTransform quirks.

```
FileStream xmlFileStream = File.Create("file.xml");
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load("transform.xsl");
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFileStream, settings);
transform.Transform(sourceXml, null, xmlWriter);
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
<xsl:template name="fillTextArea">
  <xsl:param name="sourceStr" />
    <xsl:element name="textarea">
     <xsl:attribute name="value">
       <xsl:value-of select="$sourceStr"></xsl:value-of>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="class">notes</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<textarea><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></textarea>
```

or :

```
<textarea><xsl:text><![CDATA[]]></xsl:text></textarea>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).